# Inject a local javascript into UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Is there a way to inject a local JS file or a JS file that's store on my server into any web page loaded by UIWebView?

Say I navigate to google.com in that UIWebView, it renders that page and also runs my JS file (local or on my webserver)?

Comment: You have to download the JavaScript, eg: `NSString* js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil]` then inline it with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];` and call it with `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"someFunction()"];`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following code will inject javascript locally

```
- (void)injectJavascript:(NSString *)resource {
    NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resource ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Just pass in the name of the file before the js, eg.

```
[self injectJavascript:@"script"];
```

To do inject javascript from your server you can download it first and load it into the web view in a similar manner.

Comment: By injecting it through this method you won't be able to check that the script has been successfully injected as you won't find it in the HTML code. The following link describes an alternative way (not so clean though): http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to complete [Sherman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312584/inject-a-local-javascript-into-uiwebview/7312640#7312640). Xcode defines *.js - files as source code and adds it to "Compile Sources" in project preferences, so objc returns nil, when you try to get pathForResource in mainBundle. To fix this issue you have to add your JavaScript file to "Build Phases" > "Copy Bundle Resources" in project preferences.
Hope it would be helpful, faced this problem today.