# UIWebView Height

Tags: uiwebview, scroll

I am trying to get the height of the content in my UIWebView after I have loaded the content.  I found this example somewhere...

```
NSInteger height = [[descriptionWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                     @"document.documentElement.scrollHeight"] integerValue];
```

but this just gives me the height of the UIWebView container.

I am trying to get the height of the content so I can expand the UIWebView height to show all the content with no scrolling side the webview itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script like this:

```
[[descriptionWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Oh,I forget it. before executing the code: " [[descriptionWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]; ", you may need to change the webView's frame, thus you can get the right contentHeight.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a kind of hacky, but reliable way. First, I watch for shouldStartLoadWithRequest. That catches location.href= changes. Then I just define my own protocol, e.g

```
location.href='debug://width='+$(window).height();
```

Your ObjC code catches that, checks the link, parses it and cancels the navigation.

For your own content, you can just include it, otherwise you must inject the necessary javascript. I haven't tried that myself, but there appears to be lots of solutions for it:

[Inject a local javascript into UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312584/inject-a-local-javascript-into-uiwebview)