# Is it possible modify to UIWebView content?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to add a HIDDEN field to `UIWebView` form, after HTML is loaded?

Comment: You can use  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method UIWebview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312584/inject-a-local-javascript-into-uiwebview