# UIWebView Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have three UITextfields and a submit button. I have done the validations of the textfields. But the hard part comes now. After clicking on login I have to send my textfields text to javascript, validate the credentials and after validating, my view has to move to the next view.

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{
    if (enableLogin == YES) {
      // [self loadNextView]; 
    }
}

-(void)loadNextView {

appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if (webViewDidFinishLoadBool == YES) {
    [appDelegate loginUser: txtfield1.text];
    NSLog(@"loadNextView called");
} else NSLog(@"loadNextView not called");
}


-(void)sendToJS {
//    NSString* htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pathtohtml" ofType:@"html"];
//    NSString* appHtml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
//    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath];
//    [self.webview loadHTMLString:appHtml baseURL:baseURL];
    NSURLRequest *myReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pathtohtml.html"]]];
    [self.webview loadRequest:myReq];

if (self.webview != nil) {
    jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"loginUser.login('%@', '%@', '%@');", txtfield1.text, txtfield2.text, txtfield3.text];
}
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"js loaded");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
}

  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    if ([components count] > 1 &&
        [(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"jscall"]) {
        if([(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
        {
            NSString *urlString =  (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:2];

            NSLog(@"URL STRING %@", urlString);
            if ([urlString  isEqual: @"OK"]) {
                globalValue = YES;
                webViewDidFinishLoadBool = YES;
                [self loadNextView];
                NSLog(@"is called");
            } else NSLog(@"is not called");
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is not even getting called. I even made a simple function which generates an alert but even that doesn't work..
I have set the webview delegate in viewDidLoad() and tried it in viewDidAppear()
 too.

Note: My Obj C classes are in one folder and my html and js files are in 2 separate folders.. I can't change the folder structure.

Comment: where do you use `jsCallBack`again? I see you giving it values but now using it again

Comment: @Ricardo Alves  jsCallBack is just for loading the page,,

Comment: have you tried to add js to the page. that way you can create the event on the button

Comment: @Ricardo Alves you mean calling the .js file itself? Yes I have tried that

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7312640/2164705

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116366/discussion-between-ricardo-alves-and-swift).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reloading the webview once `"enableLogin"` becomes true.